# How to pass a jwt token into the generated swagger js library

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jwt, swagger

i have documented my API endpoints via the swagger editor. (https://editor.swagger.io/)

My endpoints are protected via an JWT-Token, which needs to be send as header (like "Authorisation: Bearer ").

I can then export a JS Lib from the swagger editor.

This all works fine. The main problem is here:
My JWT is saved client-side in the localStorage.
How can i tell that generated swagger library ot use this token from the localstorage? Can i somehow hook into that library to inject the token?
And, i.E. tell what todo when i got an 401, like when the token expired? I then want the user to redirect to a certain page OR obtain a new token from my refresh token...

Appreciate your help!

Comment: When you get to the swagger page, how have you authenticated? If it's through the normal login process, just use the JWT from that.

Comment: it's not about authentication in the UI, it's about the authentification in the client library..

Comment: How does the client get the JWT token in the first place? E.g. is there a `/login` endpoint that returns the token in the response body?

Comment: Yeah.. is that the way to go by defining that login route?